# URLSessionDataTask very slow. How can I submit a request and get a response quickly?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I am looking to submit a request to hit that pulls info from an API. The API is responding quickly. Below you can see that the the session data task takes 5 seconds to respond which makes the app unbareable slow. This is for the watchOs. Am I missing something?

```
   func httpRequest(_ collection: String, httpSuccess: @escaping ((_ data: Data) -> Void), httpFailure:((_ error: NSError) -> Void)?, method: String!, params: String? = nil) {

        ....

        print(" -- ")
        printTime(string: "before request")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.printTime(string: "after  request")
                httpSuccess(data!)
            }
        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

When the code above runs, I get this in the print console window.

```
 -- 
before request: 14:23:10
after  request: 14:23:15
 -- 
before request: 14:23:15
after  request: 14:23:20
```

Comment: Maybe this link help you? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17176#thread-message-63618

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, pretty insane. Asked in Apple dev forums, will see: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/263903

Comment: I ended up using watch connectivity to send the data to the phone so the phone could process the request. That made the requests much faster.